# Create static method with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to create a spring-boot method in which all users who use my site run the queued method (without overlapping the execution?) For example, I have a method that generates a protocol number for each user according to With the date it accesses (day, month, year, hour, minute, second) but it can not happen that 2 users get the same protocol (so I want as long as a user executes that method the others wait (even if it takes a few seconds) ?

Tks

this code:

```
public synchronized Long dec() {
  return Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
}
```

This will return one unique for each user? even if one million of user access my site on same time?
tks

Answer (score 0):

### [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

> - First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods    on the same object to interleave. When one thread is
>     executing a    synchronized method for an object, all other threads
>     that invoke    synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend
>     execution)    until the first thread is done with the object.
> - Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically    establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent
>     invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This
>     guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all 
>     threads.

---

*Suggested alternative:*

### [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: so if I only use that method I edit my code will works?

Comment: Yep.  Declare the method as static synchronized and it will only execute one at a time.  Now this is a bad experience for the User so you may consider a different approach.  Perhaps using UUID to create a globally unique id.  I don't know the full extent of your requirements so that's merely a suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion only prevents the method from executing more than once at a time.  Other requests will be queued.  If you're also asking about how to create unique IDs, then my previous comment about UUIDs is a good starting point.

Comment: I don`t need to generate one protocolo, I need to create reservation app, so I need to verify if have one hour in my schedule and reserv then, so I need to garante that method will be executed for one client at time to avoid duplicate reservations